# Line element $dx$ and its "difference" to $dt$

Tags: real-analysis

In Cartesian coordinates, the line element is
$$
ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}.
$$

Often, we have $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ and hence
$$
dx=\dot{x}dt,~~dy=\dot{y}dt
$$
I think the interpretation is that a small change in $x$, which is represented by $dx$, can be interpreted as a small change in time (dt) multiplied with the "rate of change" ($\dot{x}$), and similarly for $y$.

Is that correct?

Am I right that this is a general thing: If we have a variable $z$, depending on another variable, say $z=z(y)$, then $dz$, representing a small change in $z$, is the multiplication of a small change in $y$ times the "rate of change" of $z$, represented by the derivative of $z$?

Whereas if a variable $z$ does not depend on another variable, then $dz$ again stands for a small change in $z$ but we dont have additional information about dz, only that $dz$ is a small change in z?

For example if we have 
$$
dx=\dot{x}dt,
$$
then $dt$ is just some **number** (maybe some milliseconds) while $dx$ is also a number but a number which is deduced mathematically from $dt$?

I hope you understand what I mean: $dt$ here is an elementary, physical value whereas $dx$ is some kind of mathematical approximation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, which is why I'm not writing an answer: I always think of an equation like $dx = x'dt$, which until you're doing differential geometry is technically meaningless, as being shorthand for "$\Delta x \approx x'\Delta t$ in such a way that the approximation improves 'well' as $t_f \to t_i$." (final minus initial). So from this perspective, I don't think that $dt$ has any more claim to 'physicality' than $dx$ does, unless $x$ is itself a nonphysical quantity. But given the setup, it looks like you're thinking of $x$ as a distance, which is obviously physical.

Comment: Your qualitative understanding is intuitively correct; this viewpoint underpins [Calculus Made Easy](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33283) by Sylvanus P. Thompson. A differential equation of the type $dx = \dot{x}\, dt$ (a particular expression of the chain rule) is "exact at the level of infinitesimals", or _may be treated as exact for purposes of calculation_, depending how careful you want to be with mathematical detail.

Comment: @EricStucky My point simply was that we have $\Delta x\approx x'\Delta t$ but no such approximation for $\Delta t$. $\Delta t$ is just "a value" and no other variable is involved in $\Delta t$.

Comment: The use of this is that you should regard $\Delta t$ as the *input* and $\Delta x$ as the *output*. In other words, *you* have to specify what $\Delta t$ is. The whole thing expresses $\Delta x$ in terms of $\Delta t$.

Comment: @Rhjg: What about $\Delta t \approx \frac{1}{x'}\Delta x$ ? If you object to the notation, consider that under reasonable niceness conditions, $\frac{1}{x'}$ is locally equal to $(x^{-1})'$, where $x^{-1}$ is the function that takes in an $x$-value and spits out the corresponding $t$-value; so you might reasonably write $\Delta t \approx t'\Delta x$. I think that MPW is really hitting on what you care about: dependent and independent variables. I guess my point is that, mathematically, these are not always so easily distinguished.